# PCIe Integrated Endpoint for Ultrascale 32-bit register interface issues

Tags: fpga, xilinx, pci-e

I am having some intermittent issues with reading registers from logic connected to the PCIe Integrated endpoint.  I am using a virtex ultrascale board and the register bus is mapped to bar 0.  I do 32-bit reads and writes most of the time with no issue, however I consistently get the wrong answer for a few register reads even though I can see the cc bus for these transfers and the data appears to be correct:

From the ILA core output:

```
1=s_axis_cc_tkeep
2=s_axis_cc_tdata
3=s_axis_cc_tlast
4=s_axis_cc_tready
5=s_axis_cc_tvalid
0f 000000000000000000000000000000000000001c000000008018000100040026 1 1 1
0f 000000000000000000000000000000000180c200000000008018000100040027 1 1 1
0f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000008018000100040028 1 1 1
0f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000008018000100040029 1 1 1
0f 000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000801800010004002a 1 1 1
0f 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000801800010004002b 1 1 1
```

The answers I get when I read the registers are:

```
165, 100      
166, 0         =>  hex(166&0x3f) = 0x26
167, 0         => hex(167&0x3f)  = 0x27
168, 0         => hex(168&0x3f)  = 0x28
169, 0         => hex(169&0x3f)  = 0x29
170, 100     => hex(170&0x3f) = 0x2a
171, 0         => hex(171&0x3f) = 0x2b
```

So what I don't undestand is why the transfer at 170 works but the others return 0.  I can't spot anything obvious from looking at the s_axis_cc bus.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284418/pcie-integrated-endpoint-for-ultrascale-32-bit-register-interface-issues